# Event Listener on span elements getting stuck and not resetting div when hovering over elements in quick succession

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener, letteringjs

Hey Im new to working with fetch and JSON.

I am using Lettering.js to separate the words into span elements to make them hoverable and get the innerHTML of the span element.

I have a fetch function that fetches for a translation, synonyms and word type. These then get applied to the specified divs by using .innerHTML.

My issue is when multiple span elements are hovered in quick succession
the div will stack all results without resetting and will continue even during mouseout until a span element is moused over again.

I've tried adding a reset to the divs at the beginning of the mouseover event listener and one on the mouseout event listener.

```js
function getText() {
  document.getElementById('title').innerHTML = 'Alice in wonderland'
  fetch('aliceinwonderland.txt')
  .then(function(response){
    return response.text();
  })
  .then(function(myBook) {
    let text = myBook;
    document.getElementById('hello').innerHTML = text;
  })
  .then(function(){
    $(".word_split").lettering('words');
    const word = document.getElementsByTagName('span');
    for (let i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
      word[i].addEventListener("mouseover", function(e) {
        document.querySelector('#translationOutput').innerHTML = " "
        document.getElementById('dictionaryOutput').innerHTML = " "
        document.getElementById('pos').innerHTML = " "
        e.target.style.fontWeight = 600;
        let api_key = 'trnsl.1.1.20190803T205532Z.8647ed72c2fd9935.88fa851b8a0d3b85ed70dc1ceb33a675c477242b';
        fetch('https://translate.yandex.net/api/v1.5/tr.json/translate?key=' + api_key + '&text=' + e.target.innerHTML + '&lang=fr-en&format=html')
        .then(function(response) {
          return response.json();
        })
        .then(res => {
          for (var i = 0; i < res.text.length; i++) {
            document.querySelector('#translationOutput').innerHTML = res.text[i].replace(/[^a-zA-Z ]/g, "")
          }
        });
        let api_dictionary = 'dict.1.1.20190805T202709Z.335da31d890b6512.d631a95d13606b8a5c82e663ad3f7f2760869ba1';
        fetch('https://dictionary.yandex.net/api/v1/dicservice.json/lookup?key='+ api_dictionary + '&lang=fr-en&text=' + e.target.innerHTML )
        .then(function(response) {
          return response.json();
        })
        .then(res => {
          if (res.def[0]) {
            for (let i = 0; i < res.def[0].tr.length; i++) {
              document.getElementById('dictionaryOutput').innerHTML += '<p>' + res.def[0].tr[i].text.replace(/[^a-zA-Zá]/g, "") +  ' <br></p>'
              document.getElementById('pos').innerHTML += '<p>' + res.def[0].tr[i].pos.replace(/[^a-zA-Z ]/g, "") + ' <br></p>'
              console.log(res);
            }
          } else {
            console.log('No entries')
          }
        })
      })
      word[i].addEventListener("mouseout", function(e) {
        e.target.style.fontWeight = "";
        document.querySelector('#translationOutput').innerHTML = " "
        document.getElementById('dictionaryOutput').innerHTML = " "
        document.getElementById('pos').innerHTML = " "
      });
    };
  });
};
```

Theres no error messages and the JSON data comes through without issue.
It works perfectly when going through the words slowly.

Comment: Every time you call `getText()` you're adding another `mouseover` listener to all the spans, but you're never removing the old ones.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change this:

```
word[i].addEventListener("mouseover", function(e) {..});
```

You can include this if statement inside the for loop and put the adding event listener that we changed.

```
if(word[i].className() != 'bound'){
  word[i].addClass('bound').on('mouseover', function(e) {..});
}
```